Removing integration from klaviyo dashboard but api's still working
After revoking the integration from the Klaviyo dashboard, the following API call to refresh the token continues to return a 200 OK status and provides new access and refresh tokens.
export const refresh_token = async (user_id, rToken = null) => {
  let token;
  if (user_id > 0) {
    token = await prisma.refreshToken.findFirst({
      where: { user_id: user_id },
    });
  } else {
    token = {
      refresh_token: rToken,
    };
  }

  if (!token) {
    return json({ error: 'Refresh token not found' }, { status: 404 });
  }

  try {
    const response = await fetch('https://a.klaviyo.com/oauth/token', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Authorization': `Basic ${btoa(`${process.env.KLAVIYO_CLIENT_ID}:${process.env.KLAVIYO_CLIENT_SECRET}`)}`,
      },
      body: new URLSearchParams({
        'grant_type': 'refresh_token',
        'refresh_token': token.refresh_token,
      }),
    });

    let res = await response.json();
    console.log("response _______________________________", res);

    if (!response.ok) {
      const errorData = await response.json();
      console.error('Error response from Klaviyo:', errorData);
      return json({ error: 'Failed to refresh token' }, { status: response.status });
    }

    const responseData = await response.json();

    if (user_id > 0) {
      await prisma.refreshToken.update({
        where: { id: token.id },
        data: { refresh_token: responseData.refresh_token },
      });

      await prisma.$disconnect();
    }

    return responseData.access_token;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error during token refresh:', error);
    return json({ error: 'Failed to refresh token due to an unexpected error' }, { status: 500 });
  }
};

I tried making get event call to check weather tokens still working or not and unfortunately they work. I expect that removing integration from klaviyo dashboard should results in unauthenticated
